# How can I increase the allowed execution time for a CSOM Client Context?

Tags: client-object-model, csom

I am running SharePoint 2013 and have a Windows app that creates SharePoint sites with CSOM.

I have used Powershell to adjust the ClientCallableSettings, lengthening the ExecutionTimeout to 3 minutes. That is successful.

I have set the `ExecutionTimeout` of my `ClientContext` to **3*60*1000**, which is 3 minutes.

I have changed a web.config file that is located at `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\80` of my SharePoint server to say

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="51200" executionTimeout="300" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```

and have reset IIS, but I’m not sure about this being the appropriate `web.config`.

I am still getting timeouts at about 110 seconds (more or less) and I can’t stand it.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue recently and solve it by increasing the Client Callback Execution Timeout. I set it using PowerShell ,

```
$webapp = Get-SPWebApplication -Identity http://webapplicationXYZ
$webapp.ClientCallableSettings.ExecutionTimeout = [System.Timespan]::FromMinutes(5)
$webapp.Update()
```

And In web.config file you can put it like:

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="512000" requestLengthDiskThreshold="512000" executionTimeout="999999" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```

Comment: This is exactly what OP says has been performed, with no success

Comment: As far as I understood he/she updated in web.config file. He need to update it in web application level. And my case it was same issue, it was timed out around 110 seconds. And worked  after I increase the value in webapplication.

Comment: The second paragraph in the question seems to mention doing this with powershell? But it's great that your answer explains how to do this

Comment: Hi Robert, you are right. Some how I missed it. Sorry .....